# Alternative to AdSense that allows ad refresh when user interacts with site

Tags: javascript

I have a website that's all AJAX, thus no page refreshes. I just discovered AdSense TOS doesn't allow refreshing ads.

I'm looking for an ad network that allows the ad space to be refreshed when a user is interacting with the page. The ads won't be refreshed on a time interval, but I wouldn't oppose doing that if it's the only option.